Migrating From Google less secure apps to Google API for sending mails in Java webapp
Actually, I'm using Google mail with less secure apps setup in java webapp.
Google decided to deprecate this functionality and I have to migrate to use Google API to send mails through Oauth2
I tried several options, including the Google documentation but with no luck. I'm very stressed because I need it solved before Google shut down less secure apps compatibility.
I have a Google Workspace Account for non-profit, which means that I have full access to all Suite.
I created a Full Access Service Account.
I enabled Google Gmail API.
I created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID with an authorized URL redirection to http://localhost:8080/ROOT/oauth2callback
I created an OAuth consent screen.
This is my java code:
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

/* class to demonstrate use of Gmail list labels API */
public class GmailQuickstart {
  /**
   * Application name.
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
  /**
   * Global instance of the JSON factory.
   */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  /**
   * Directory to store authorization tokens for this application.
   */
  private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

  /**
   * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
   * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
   */
  private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);

  /**
   * Creates an authorized Credential object.
   *
   * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
   * @return An authorized Credential object.
   * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
   */
  private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
      File file = new File("/a/b/tokens/eac-webapp-client_secret.json");
      FileInputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(credentialsStream));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(43513).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    //returns an authorized Credential object.
    return credential;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();

    // Print the labels in the user's account.
    String user = "me";
    ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
    List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
    if (labels.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No labels found.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Labels:");
      for (Label label : labels) {
        System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
      }
    }
  }
}

The file I'm using to create the GoogleClientSecrets is the one I get from OAuth 2.0 Client ID.
But always, at the moment when executing authorize method, the received message when opens in browser is Access blocked: This app's request is invalid (Check de screenshot)


And I'm blocked at this point.
Has anybody an idea to solve this situation?
UPDATE:
I'm trying to understand why google is giving me this information:
request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/Callback flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
What is this URL? What is intended for?, I have to develop something in there?
Thank you all.
g2h2o
